# Detect when user is trying to rotate screen

Tags: android

Basically I have `Activity`, which contains this line in the manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

So I can't rotate it and it's always in a portrait mode.

The issue is that I need to detect whenever user is trying to rotate the screen. I've already watched questions like : [Remove orientation restricitons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829568/remove-orientation-restricitons-programmatically) , [How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android) and so on.

By now I know that to do it you need t override this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

And, in my case to use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

To allow screen rotation. The issue in this approach is that I have a lot of fragments and will need to make sure that it wont affect others, which I don't want to do.

Question : Is there some way to have a listener when user is trying to make a screen rotation, but when you don't allow him to do so, in that way fragment wont change it's orientation, but I'll catch screen rotation action.

Please help!

Comment: Even when you don't allow rotation, sensors are working. Invoke them to detect rotation.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614439/how-to-detect-my-screen-orientation-in-portrait-locked-screen-in-android. Do have a look

Comment: Thx for responses, i will look into