# set screen orientation for Fragment Manager - Android

Tags: android

I want to rotate my app when the landscape mode is activated, and to be fixed in Portrait mode(like a normal app).
As I use a fragment manager, I decided to create an init method to programmatically decide to rotate or not my app instead of doing rotation for every fragments.
here's the method:

```
public class ActivityHelper {
    public static void initialize(Activity activity) {
        int orientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app always stays in Portrait mode.
Does someone have an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you recreating the activity?

Comment: no I pass it from the controller : ActivityHelper.initialize(this);

Comment: After you set the requested orientation, I would try `activity.recreate()`

Comment: doesn't work either :/

Comment: I think you have an issue in your code, i would have a look at this question : 
[Remove orientation restrictions programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829568/remove-orientation-restricitons-programmatically)